# Read text file from Python and use corresponding variable

Tags: python, text

I just started Python and would like to read the following text file and use the variable values:
Textfile 'r1': (Variable name and its value)

```
    mu |  cs |  co
------------------
    5  |  100|  300 
------------------
```

I have the following code:

with open("r1.txt") as file1:
    data = file1.read()

it could be printed but f returns no value.

How could I use the variable in the text file for later use (mu, cs, co)?

Ex: I would like to generate a poisson distribution,

Can I write:

```
    G = poisson(data.mu)
```

It seems not, but how could I call the corresponding varilables in the dataset?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Which means to use the following: G = poisson(d['mu'])  right after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you used the `read` function (in the `print` command), the file has already been read, so second reading gives nothing. You should assign reading to some variable, such as

```
with open("r1.txt") as file:
   lines = file.read()
```

so that you can go back to `lines` in the future.

But if you want to assign specific variables to specific values read from file, you need to parse it. Here, it depends heavily on the specific format your data is in.

Comment: Thank you! Following this logic, can I call 'file.mu' / 'file.co' later on to use the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should read two lines first, then parse them, and finally use it as dict

```
with open("r1.txt") as fp:
    lines = [line for line in fp]
    keys = [s.strip() for s in lines[0].split('|')]  # key line
    vals = [s.strip() for s in lines[2].split('|')]  # value line
    f = dict(zip(keys, vals))
    print(f)
```

then, you could use `f['mu']` for then mu value.

Comment: Thank you! Following this logic, how can I call mu, cs or co then?

Comment: in more detail, `G = poisson(f['mu'])`, you could see usage of dict in Python

Comment: Thanks @jerliol  I tried that but it says: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> KeyError: 'mu'      And if I write mu = f['mu'] it returns same error.

Comment: try to debug you code due to your file's format may be not same as you said, like my updated code, print is normally simplest way to debug